# How we can transform image from plane to vector?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm new in Computer Vision, but I'm want to discover this domain.
Now I learn how to detect spatial-temporal interest points. To this, I've read [this](https://www.irisa.fr/vista/Papers/2005_ijcv_laptev.pdf) article of Ivan Laptev.

So, I stuck on transformation image from R2(plane) to R1(vector). (in this article paragraph 2.1 in the start):

> In the spatial domain, we can model an image f(sp):R^2->R  its  linear  scale-space  representation (Witkin,  1983;  Koenderink  and  van  Doorn,  1992;
>   Lindeberg, 1994; Florack, 1997) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydS3W.gif)

I don't understand, how we get 1(image from R^2, R)
Can somebody give good article about this, or explain by himself?
As I understand, we use convolution with Gaussian kernel to this. But, after convolution we get also image R^2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you model your image as a function `f(x,y)` you pass values in `R^2` (one dimension for each, `x` and one for `y`). And you get a one dimensional output (scalar) for each pair of `x` and `y`, right? Just stupid math:-)

Comment: I thought about that, but image have 3 channels(for example in RGB), and I don't understand how author of  this article meant convert RGB notation to 1 number

Comment: I guess he is implying a single channel respectively gray value image. Salient feature extraction often gets along with that.

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph just state that the function operates on a neighborhood in R^2 and returns a scalar. This is true for a Gaussian it takes a neighborhood around a point and returns a scalar which is a weighted sum of the pixels in the neighborhood as a function of there location in relation to the center of the neighborhood.